# Bootstrap styles are not rendering in asp.net gridview and showing some other class

Tags: html, css, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I am revamping my old asp.net web application and making it responsive. I used ace-master template which uses bootstrap. I have a gridview in my page. I changed my gridview code like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <!-- PAGE CONTENT BEGINS -->
        <div>

            <div id="dynamic-table_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline no-footer">

                <asp:GridView ID="dgTradename" runat="server" Width="100%" DataKeyNames="TradeNameId" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="dgTradename_RowDataBound" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="even" RowStyle-CssClass="odd"
                    AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="dgTradename_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCommand="dgTradename_RowCommand"
                    UseAccessibleHeader="true" GridLines="Both">

                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TradeNameNo" HeaderText="Trade Name No" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:BoundField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Owner Name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                            <ItemTemplate><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "dtoOwner.NameEn")%></ItemTemplate>

                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:TemplateField>


                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>


        </div>
        <!-- PAGE CONTENT ENDS -->
    </div>
</div>
```

But while rendering the code, html code for table is showing a css class 'GridView' and the required bootstrap css is not rendered

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <!-- PAGE CONTENT BEGINS -->
        <div>

            <div id="dynamic-table_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline no-footer">


                <div>
    <table class="GridView" id="ctl00_PageBody_ctlSearchTradeName1_dgTradename" style="border-style:None;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <thead>
            <tr class="Header">
                <th scope="col">Trade Name No</th><th scope="col">Owner Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead><tbody>
            <tr class="Row">
                <td align="left">114</td><td align="left">Honj</td>
            </tr><tr class="AlternatingRow">
                <td align="left">909</td><td align="left"> Internet Cafe Tr</td>
            </tr><tr class="Pager">
                <td colspan="6"><table border="0">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td><span class="editBox" style="display:inline-block;border-style:Solid;width:200px;">1</span></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$PageBody$ctlSearchTradeName1$dgTradename','Page$2')">2</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$PageBody$ctlSearchTradeName1$dgTradename','Page$3')">3</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$PageBody$ctlSearchTradeName1$dgTradename','Page$4')">4</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$PageBody$ctlSearchTradeName1$dgTradename','Page$5')">5</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$PageBody$ctlSearchTradeName1$dgTradename','Page$6')">6</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$PageBody$ctlSearchTradeName1$dgTradename','Page$7')">7</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$PageBody$ctlSearchTradeName1$dgTradename','Page$8')">8</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$PageBody$ctlSearchTradeName1$dgTradename','Page$9')">9</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
            </div>


        </div>
        <!-- PAGE CONTENT ENDS -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried

1. Removing all other css class from the application
2. Removing all cache from the browser
3. Clean and rebuild the solution

Please don't consider this as a duplicate question as i have tried all answers from different stackoverflow questions

Comment: from the moment you have set the `CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer"` and you get something else, then you have an inside change of this css, somewhere in your code. Just search it out

Comment: I had an old css which contains this 'Gridview' style. I completely removed that file from the solution.

Comment: Now what I did is added a css replace code in Page_Load. That worked. But that is not a proper solution

Comment: Well, not complete from what its looks like - for some reason something is still change it to that. Maybe if you shut down the IIS, and the VS, and delete the temporary files of asp.net

Comment: Sure I will try that and get back...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a week, I found the issue.

I have some skins added in my solution. Even if it is not referred anywhere, its using from back. I removed that skins from my solution and now the bootstrap styles are rendered